# Creating a Card with a center icon and bottom row

Tags: flutter

I'm new to Flutter and I'm attempting to create a Card that has a bottom row and a center Icon or Text.  I'm sure this is pretty easy, but I'm struggling .  I'm not sure of the best way to do this.  Should I create a column with two nested columns?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Test extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Card(
        elevation: 5,
        margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16, 16, 16, 0),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Icon(
              Icons.ac_unit,
              color: Colors.blue,
            ),
            Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  child: Container(
                    height: 50,
                    color: Colors.blue,
                  ),
                )
              ],
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try out this code.

```dart
Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    Expanded(
      child: Center(
        child: Text('\$250'),
      ),
    ),
    Text('\$ Total'),
  ],
)
```

I'm using Expanded to use entire space of container (`Column`) which will push text to the bottom. And using `Center` to put a widget (`Text` in this code) in the middle of the container.

Comment: Makes sense now!  Thank you so much, I got it working by your example.